# React page not rendering from top

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am using React 16.6.0. I have multiple pages in my project but I was asked on question why page are rendering from middle like

When I am in first page bottom there I have one link navigate to another page; if I click on that link then it opens another page at same the position 
but I want to display from top means (navbar or header) but it was showing only where I was in first page position in second page.

I have tried many times using window.location.reload() in componentDidMount but it didn't work for me.

Comment: please show html/js code of your problem and how exactly it behaves

Comment: Please add your code, so we can take a look

Comment: do you want to me to add router code?

Comment: I don't know what readers will want, but yes, add your router code. It is not ideal to post a question with no code at all, since that is much less likely to get answers - post something at least.

Comment: Yes, show the code. It sounds like your router code is too low in the containment hierarchy - it should be near the top (unless you have a reason for that)

Comment: I was facing the same issue. I used `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` on click event of buttons.